# Бот ищет нужное сообщение

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, elasticsearch

Есть группа, в которой есть бот, но нет пользователя, который будет запрашивать необходимое сообщение (по заголовку) у бота. Через что можно реализовать данную функцию. Есть предложения через elastiсsearch, но может есть проще варианты

Comment: Если никто не будет запрашивать, то по какому критерию бот должен искать сообщение?

Comment: Пользователь зная тему сообщения запрашивает его у бота, бот ищет сообщение в группе и отправляет его пользователю. Пользователь не должен состоять в этой группе.